# Confirmation delete message kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a `Kendo MVC grid` where I want to delete a record from it.

When I use their `Destroy` command it generates a confirmation popup with the following text: "*Are you sure you want to delete this record?*".

Instead of the message I would like to display something else, for example: "*Do you really really really want to do this?*"

**Is there a straight forward way to do this ?**

Thank you

Comment: You could use the kendo.messages.xx localization files

Comment: The problem ia that i want to change only a specific message, not all of them. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the text in the editable confirmation property of the grid:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable.confirmation

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   editable: {
     confirmation: "Do you really really really want to do this?"
   }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but now I have 2 of them, the old one and the new one!

Comment: @LuisGouveia, can you create a Dojo/CodePen that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0):

DisplayDeleteConfirmation worked for me. If you created your GridView with Html.Raw by the way.

```
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).DisplayDeleteConfirmation("I'm asking again ara you u sure ?"))
            .Events(e => e.Save("onGridSave"))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:300px;width:600px;" })
```